# Is $y=0$ an asymptote to the function $f(x)=\frac{2x-2}{x+1}$?

Tags: functions

If you graph the function $f(x)=\frac{2x-2}{x+1}$ it can be seen that the x-axis is an asymptote to the function as it tends to infinity in both directions but the function does cross the x-axis at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

In these cases is $y=0$ considered an asymptote?

Answer (score 2):

The $x$ axis is **not** an asymptote to the function, you can clearly see this by plotting the function.

The graph should look something like [this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(2x-2)%2F(x%2B1)%20from%20-10%20to%2010)

Answer (score 2):

The line $y = a x + b$ is an asymptote if
$$\lim |f(x) - (ax+b)| = 0$$
when $x$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or both).

In your case, $y=0$ is not an asymptote.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\frac{2x-2}{x+1}=\frac{2x+2-4}{x+1}=\frac{2(x+1)-4}{x+1}=2-\frac{4}{x+1}$$